# How to display results in notification bar on Android

Tags: android

I'm creating an Android application. What I'm looking for is after computing the results I want the numeric value to be displayed on the notification window. How can I do it?

Comment: Please, share you source code, so that we could at least understand your current status and help you.

Comment: Ok sir... Sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display your result into notification you can use below code to create notification:

```
 Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.noti_icon);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti_icon)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setContentTitle("Your Title of Notification")
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setContentText("write here your score which you have counted");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class); // here on notification click you are moved on this activity

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.visibility |= Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC;


    notificationId = 0;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

Comment: Accept my answer if you are satisfied. (Check on arrow shows left to the answer )